# Finding a book involving a boy and carnival which consisted of radical environmentalists

Tags: identification-request

In 2008 I read a book (fiction) about a boy living with a carnival. The carnival was a bunch of radical environmentalists. I can't recall the title or the author so I'm hoping somebody on here can help me.

I read the book whilst sitting beside my mother's bed in hospital and I have brain fog about that period of time.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature SE. Could you also tell us which language the book was in? Do you remember any other details, e.g. the book cover? Was it aimed at a specific age group?

Comment: Also, anything about the plot would be a huge help. Was the boy born to carnival people or adopted by them? Does their radical environmentalism cause them or him any trouble? What happens in the story really, beyond the setting which you've described?

Comment: It was in English, adult fiction. The people were involved in radical environmenal action like Earth First. That is pretty much all I can recall I'm afraid. It was a pretty fraught time (especially as my father died a few months later).